# webspehere MQ conection remains open in the server

Tags: java, ibm-mq

Occasionally when my Java program gets an internal error and terminates, the connection to the MQ channel remains established. 
Strangely the java code is not running on my machine, but in MQ explorer,  it is shown as connected .

1. Is there is any process/service running in my machine which I can terminate manually to close the connection ?
2. Can you tell me what is the likely reason for this ( i am using connection.close / channel.close and queue.close) and what could be the likely

Regards
Abhinav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there is any process/service running in my machine which I can
>   terminate manually to close the connection ?

You need to include try/catch logic in your code and when you have an issue, then in the catch clause, have your code call its cleanup logic (i.e. close queues and disconnect from the queue manager).

> Can you tell me what is the likely reason for this ( i am using
>   connection.close / channel.close and queue.close) and what could be
>   the likely

Obviously, you are not and it conflicts with your earlier statement of:

> when my Java program gets an internal error and terminates,

Therefore, add the appropriate try/catch logic and properly close queues and disconnect from the queue manager even when bad things go wrong in your program.

Answer (score 0):

You can add below method in finally:

```
private void cleanUp() {
        if (producer != null) {
            try {
                producer.close();
            } catch (JMSException jmsex) {
                logger.error("WebSphereMQMessageSender. cleanUp: Producer could not be closed.");
                recordFailure(jmsex);
            }
        }
        if (session != null) {
            try {
                session.close();
            } catch (JMSException jmsex) {
                logger.error("WebSphereMQMessageSender. cleanUp: Session could not be closed.");
                recordFailure(jmsex);
            }
        }
        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (JMSException jmsex) {
                logger.error("WebSphereMQMessageSender. cleanUp: Connection could not be closed.");
                recordFailure(jmsex);
            }
        }
    }
```

for more information see [this](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/SendMessagesToWebSphereMQ70).

Comment: @Roger : Is there any service or process which I can close to end this connection explicitly ?